# Are RAM modules above DDR3 1600MHz overclocked speeds?

Tags: memory, speed, ddr3

I see a lot of DDR3 memory speeds out there.  Are memory speeds above 1600MHz overclocked speeds?  I am specifically referring to the DDR3 standard.  Or if my motherboard supports the speed I am good to go opt for a higher speed RAM?

My PC has a Core i7-4790K running on an ASUS Z97 SABERTOOTH MARK 1.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you define overclocking. The modules are definitely not overclocked, because the are sold this way.

The motherboard (well, the ultimately CPU-integrated memory controller) might have to operate outside its specified range. This may or may not be harmful.

Slightly OT: Faster memory usually won’t get you anywhere. More memory will.

**Update:**

Your CPU, an i7-4790K, supports up to DDR3-1600 as per specifications. With XMP active, it probably won’t have any problem going higher. For example, I’m using an i5-2500K (albeit at 4 GHz), which is officially maxed at DDR3-1333, at DDR3-1600. I have been from the start (well over 3 years ago) and never encountered any problems.

Your motherboard, the Sabertooth Z98 Mk I, is rated for DDR3-1866. This may or may not limit—my board is rated for DDR3-2133. (Not that there’s any CPU supporting this, heh.)

Comment: Most Intel CPU's support only 1333/1600 MHz speeds so I can say that if my motherboard supports 1866 and I put in 1866 modules ill be OC the system in a way? Actually I don't want to overclock at all

Comment: It would be simpler to answer if you’d actually name your motherboard and CPU model...

Comment: It's Intel Core i7-4790K on ASUS Z97 SABERTOOTH MARK 1.

Comment: @LoneWOLFs I’ve updated my answer. (And your question. :P)

Comment: So basically 1600MHz is the way to go I think if you don't intend to oc and mess up things more. Although it might sound stupid to buy a 'K' series processor I want to clarify that the base clock speed of 4GHz was the point in getting it. :)